# java.nio.channels.*

Tags: java

What is up with nio channels ? There were some nice talks when it was added to java but I still don't see people using it in their applications.

Is there something wrong with it, or am I just not encountering people who use it?

Any nice examples as to why I should bother using it at all ?

Thanks

Comment: The title of the question should be changed to something like 'What are the advantages of the "java.nio.channels" classes?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking about channels, but channels only make sense within the general framework of using the (relatively) new `nio` capabilities as a whole.

My guess is that of the many, many Java applications out in the world, not many *need* the capabilities of `nio`. The usual "business" process read streams and/or files... nothing special.

That said, the Apache folks have recently rewritten their core Java libraries ( http://hc.apache.org/ ) to use `nio`, and claim some impressive performance benefits in some cases.

`nio` also lets you do stuff like memory-mapping files, and this can allow an application to do very fast random access to the file. Again, only some special applications need this, and that's probably why you don't see a lot of it used.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) is a great networking library and uses NIO.

> Apache MINA is a network application framework which helps users develop high performance and high scalability network applications easily. It provides an abstract · event-driven · asynchronous API over various transports such as TCP/IP and UDP/IP via Java NIO.

Answer (score 2):

[Net4J](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Net4j), a signaling platform/framework, makes heavy use of NIO channels. (One part of Net4J basically provides a convenience API to NIO channels.)